# Connecting to ubuntu server (SSH), how to stop terminating process after logout?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I connecting from laptop to my ubuntu-server via SSH, log into the system, and execute, for example, a command like

```
apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless
```

The download starts, but if I close my SSH connection the process is terminated. How can I handle it to stop process terminating after log-out? Is it possible and safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (in most of the cases) and safe. The command should be something like:

```
nohup apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless >/path/to/log 2>/path/to/errors &
```

`nohup` command deattach the process from terminal (like a daemon) and `&` put it in background

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `nohup`

```
nohup apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless &
```

If I remember well, the command won't stop if you close your ssh session and will write the output into a file named `nohup.out`

You also can use screen
https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen